# I'm trying to get my Python Code to click on a button if a condition isn't matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, python-tesseract, pyautogui

Currently it gives a click once the condition is met.

For example:

The code looks for a particular word on my screen. It matches with a set of data I have defined already.

**How it should work:**

- If the screen has nothing on it, a click occurs.
- If the screen has the word "cookie" on it, it beeps and exits.

**What is occuring:**

- If the screen has nothing on it, a click occurs.
- The screen has the word "cookie" on it. It clicks. It beeps and
  exits.

**Sample Output:**

- No common elements.
- No common elements.
- No common elements.
- {'cookie'}

The Third *"No common elements"*, shouldn't have occured. The word cookie appeared after the second click. There's something wrong in how the if-else condition is being accessed. Thoughts?

Code below:

```
import pytesseract
import numpy as nm
import winsound
import pyautogui
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab

def imToString():
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    while (True):

        source = [
"chocolate", "muffin", "cookie"
                 ]

        cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(748, 626, 916, 646))

        tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            cv2.cvtColor(nm.array(cap), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
            lang='eng')

        split_words =tesstr.split()

        normalized_input = [word.rstrip('.,!?').lower() for word in split_words]
        source_normalized = [word.lower() for word in source]

        set_a = set(source_normalized)
        set_b = set(normalized_input)
        match = set_a & set_b

        if match:
            print(match)
            frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
            duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
            winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
            return False
        else:
            print("No common elements")
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.moveTo(826,309)
            pyautogui.click()


imToString()
```

Any inputs on what mistake I am making?

Comment: are you sure you are giving tesseract the image you're thinking ? it's not clear how you pass the data to the OCR. By the way there are several things I would change. You don't need to redefine each time the source vector of words to look for (neither lower case them), you can do that once before the while true.

Comment: Yeah I'll be changing the code to define the source before while. Yeah it's reading the image correctly from a portion of my screen once the click refreshes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up my code, and used the any() function as a check for the if-else block. Code is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
if match:
    print(match)
    frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
    duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
    winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
    # the while true stops here, you don't have the time to see the answer
    return False
```

maybe add:

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

before return.

Comment: I've updated my question with some additional information to provide clarity. Could you take a look?